# Sql query for following condition

Tags: sql

**Question**: Write Sql query for creating session numbers for users. Session = if two consecutive records are within 30 min of each other, its the same session.

```
| User_id | impression_ts |  
+---------+---------------+ 
|   101   |    10:30 AM   |
|   101   |    10:45 AM   |
|   101   |    10:50 AM   |
|   101   |    11:30 AM   |
|   101   |    12:30 PM   |
|   101   |    12:35 PM   |
```

**Output:**

```
| User_id | impression_ts | session |
+---------+---------------+---------+
|   101   |  10:30 AM     |    1    |
|   101   |  10:45 AM     |    1    |
|   101   |  10:50 AM     |    1    |
|   101   |  11:30 AM     |    2    |
|   101   |  12:30 PM     |    3    |
|   101   |  12:35 PM     |    3    |
```

Comment: Hi @user3330703, you have tag for more than one database. What database do you use ?

Comment: Please do not tag different kind of databases. As the SQL dialects are different there will be no single answer possible for anybody

Comment: @user3330703 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select 
    user_id,
    impression_ts,
    sum(case when impression_ts <= dateadd(minute, 30, lag_impression_ts) then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp_ts) session
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(impression_ts) over(partition by user_id order by impression_ts) lag_impression_ts
    from mytable t
) t
```

This uses SQL Server date arithmetics. In MySQL, you would need to change the expression inside the window sum to:

```
case when impression_ts <= lag_impression_ts + interval 30 minute then 0 else 1 end
```

In Postgres:

```
case when impression_ts <= lag_impression_ts + interval '30 minute' then 0 else 1 end
```